# I keep getting a NullReferenceException when I try to stop a Timer from within a custom class

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have a timer that I created using the Form designer (that makes it a member of the main form window right? ) I stop the timer in a different method in this class. Currently I have it working by passing it into the other method and assiging to `t`, a private member of this class. I realize that it COULD be null when this happens, but its not when I debug it and its driving me nuts.

`System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
        private void domDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do a doc scan here then remove the handler

        var form = Form.ActiveForm as MainWindow;
        form.pagesToVisit = docScan(b.Document, this.domain);

        if (t != null) { t.Start(); }
        // here i need to stop a timer that is a member of the main form


        b.DocumentCompleted -= domDocumentCompleted;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your code is inside an event. The event may be getting called in a separate thread from the one the main form operates under. See [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
 for how to get around this.

Also, it's not good practice to remove an event from inside the event.

Comment: I'm pretty sure due to the simplicity that this isn't getting called from anywhere else. 

_Also, it's not good practice to remove an event from inside the event._ Why is this, and what is another way I could accomplish the same thing given that the page loads take time.